# How can I get a kernel's execution time with NSight Compute 2019 CLI?

Tags: cuda, command-line-interface, profiling, nsight-compute

Suppose I have an executable `myapp` which needs no command-line argument, and launches a CUDA kernel `mykernel`. I can invoke:

```
nv-nsight-cu-cli -k mykernel myapp
```

and get output looking like this:

```
==PROF== Connected to process 30446 (/path/to/myapp)
==PROF== Profiling "mykernel": 0%....50%....100% - 13 passes
==PROF== Disconnected from process 1234
[1234] myapp@127.0.0.1
  mykernel(), 2020-Oct-25 01:23:45, Context 1, Stream 7
    Section: GPU Speed Of Light
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
    Memory Frequency                      cycle/nsecond      1.62
    SOL FB                                %                  1.58
    Elapsed Cycles                        cycle              4,421,067
    SM Frequency                          cycle/nsecond      1.43
    Memory [%]                            %                  61.76
    Duration                              msecond            3.07
    SOL L2                                %                  0.79
    SM Active Cycles                      cycle              4,390,420.69
    (etc. etc.)
    --------------------------------------------------------------------
    (etc. etc. - other sections here)
```

so far - so good. But now, I just want the overall kernel duration of `mykernel` - and no other output. Looking at `nv-nsight-cu-cli --query-metrics`, I see, among others:

```
gpu__time_duration           incremental duration in nanoseconds; isolated measurement is same as gpu__time_active
gpu__time_active             total duration in nanoseconds
```

So, it must be one of these, right? But when I run

```
nv-nsight-cu-cli -k mykernel myapp --metrics gpu__time_duration,gpu__time_active
```

I get:

```
==PROF== Connected to process 30446 (/path/to/myapp)
==PROF== Profiling "mykernel": 0%....50%....100% - 13 passes
==PROF== Disconnected from process 12345
[12345] myapp@127.0.0.1
  mykernel(), 2020-Oct-25 12:34:56, Context 1, Stream 7
    Section: GPU Speed Of Light
    Section: Command line profiler metrics
    ---------------------------------------------------------------
    gpu__time_active                                   (!) n/a
    gpu__time_duration                                 (!) n/a
    ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

My questions:

- Why am I getting "n/a" values?
- How can I get the actual values I'm after, and nothing else?

Notes: :

- I'm using CUDA 10.2 with NSight Compute version 2019.5.0 (Build 27346997).
- I realize I can filter the standard output stream of the unqualified invocation, but that's not what I'm after.
- I actually just want the raw number, but I'm willing to settle for using `--csv` and taking the last field.
- Couldn't find anything relevant in the [nvprof transition guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/nsight-compute/NsightComputeCli/index.html#nvprof-metric-comparison).

Comment: @RobertCrovella I think this one's for you :-)

Comment: Metrics like this normally have a qualifier defining the type of arithmetic used in the measurement.  Try asking for `gpu__time_active.max`.  In newer versions of nsight compute (e.g. 2020.2), it is also possible to ask for the base metric i.e. `gpu__time_active` and it prints out all the metric variants it knows of: `.max`, `.avg`, `.sum`, etc.  But I tested version 2019.5.0 and it doesn't do that; if you don't give a fully qualified metric it prints `n/a`.  I don't know how to get the actual values and nothing else, unless you use some filtering method, which you've stated you don't want.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: How do I list all of the variants, for an arbitrary metric? Or all metrics?

Comment: one possible method, according to my testing: switch to a newer version of nsight compute, and if you ask for `gpu__time_active` it will give you the metric for all available variants.  I've responded to your questions as best I can, and you're up to at least 4 now in this question.  I won't be able to respond further here, it's outside of the way SO expects the Q+A site to work.  regarding your latest question(s), I would also refer to this: https://docs.nvidia.com/cupti/Cupti/r_main.html#r_host_derived_metrics_api

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Damn, no variance, nor standard deviation :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr: You need to specify the appropriate 'submetric':**

```
nv-nsight-cu-cli -k mykernel myapp --metrics gpu__time_active.avg
```

---

<sub>(Based on @RobertCrovella's comments)</sub>

CUDA's profiling mechanism collects 'base metrics', which are indeed listed with `--list-metrics`. For each of these, multiple samples are taken. In version 2019.5 of NSight Compute you *can't* just get the raw samples; you can only get 'submetric' values.

'Submetrics' are essentially some aggregation of the sequence of samples into a scalar value. Different metrics have different kinds of submetrics (see [this listing](https://docs.nvidia.com/cupti/Cupti/r_main.html#r_host_derived_metrics_api)); for `gpu__time_active`, these are: `.min`, `.max`, `.sum`, `.avg`. Yes, if you're wondering - they're missing second-moment metrics like the variance or the sample standard deviation.

So, you must either specify one or more submetrics (see example above), or alternatively, upgrade to a [newer version of NSight Compute](https://developer.nvidia.com/nsight-compute), with which you actually *can* just get all the samples apparently.